# Does this action fall under riyaa or waswaas?

Tags: shirk, waswasa

So I was reciting the Quran in my room, I was alone and I recited loudly (not purposely). At the start I said that I'm reciting for the sake of Allah (SWT) only. But as I was reciting, I felt like I was showing off by reciting beautifully and loudly. I'm pretty sure it was waswaas and I tried ignoring it. But as I kept reciting, I thought that there were people in front of me and I recited even better. So my doubt is, if you are alone in your room and you are reciting the Quran and you want to recite beautifully so you pretend that people are in front of you.. Is this considered as riyaa (showing off) or is it just the waswaas confusing me?